# LM741 Cross-Over distortion

Tags: operational-amplifier, distortion, zero-crossing

Could anyone explain why I may see cross-over distortion in my output signal of this op-amp circuit?

[image]

The input is a 1Vpp sine wave at a frequency of 10kHz, with no DC offset. I am definitely seeing that it is happening, but I'm unsure how I could have predicted it.

Comment: Can we have a photo or screen grab?

Comment: friends dont let friends use >20 year old opamps

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/341843/adding-a-resistor-to-reduce-crossover-distortion-in-an-lm324-lm358

Comment: Sorry I don't have a screen grab. It's not clipping, it just looks like your stereotypical cross-over distortion (weird slanted effect near zero volts). Also, this is for an educational lab, specifically using the older op-amps so that it's easier to see the "practical" side of the op-amp instead of just the ideal.

Comment: @BeB00 LM741 has a different output stage from the common single-supply LM358/LM324 (class AB) so it's actually superior (in that one way). OP: Do you have any loading on the amplifier output? Also, are you sure it's actually a 741?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Isn't the resistor in the feedback path a load?

Comment: @thebusybee It is, but not a large one. I'm not sure what the bias current is in the AB stage, but that load is less than +/-300uA.

Comment: 10 kHz, 6Vp-p output must be pushing pretty close to the slew rate limit of the 741. Calculate the expected slew rate for this signal and compare with the datasheet. As slew rate limiting happens on the steepest portion of the waveform, maybe you're mistaking it for crossover? Without a phone pic it's difficult to know. But I bet it disappears at 1 kHz.