# Forcing the bias current of a voltage feedback amp into a larger Class AB by a resistor

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, current-source, bias, class-ab

Can I force any voltage feedback amp to flow current in one side of its output stage (therefore moderate over-biasing it to work in an extended class-AB area), by simply connecting a power resistor from the output to one of the opposite supply rails?

I know this is not optimal because the resistor is not a constant current source.

Once determined the AMP heat limit and the reduced output power now available, which could be the theoretical optimum class AB bias current, and, thus, the desired incremental current I could force by introducing that resistor?

(The output stage of the Power AMP, in this design treated as a unity gain buffer or voltage follower for semplicity, could be in class B, or already slight biased in class AB.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkAbko.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a resistor to reduce crossover distortion in an LM324/LM358](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/341843/adding-a-resistor-to-reduce-crossover-distortion-in-an-lm324-lm358)

Comment: Useful but doesn't answer. I know it is possible with a single op-amp. I'm asking for any "black box" power amplifier (why shouldn't work) where the output buffer stage already employs emitter followers in class AB amplifier, generally push-pull amplifiers using two complementary or matching transistors, one being an NPN-type and the other being a PNP-type.

Comment: Your "output "bias" resistor is reducing the maximum output power by stealing some of the positive-going current that would normally go to the load. It does not change the operating point voltage of 0V. Instead it messes up the maximum load current symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It will work as far as changing the operating point of the output stage and forcing it into class A.

But this is done not for fun, but presumably to reduce distortion. Whether it does actually do that depends on how much active control there is on the output stage bias, and how good the design is, basically.

Many op-amps have very little crossover distortion as long as they are operated at a small fraction of their bandwidth: the external feedback and high speed are enough to move the output stage quickly to where it needs to be.

With modern active biasing wideband integrated amplifier designs, crossover distortion is a non-issue. It gets harder to do the more power you need of course, and the higher power stages tend to be slower and not quick enough to compensate just by the external negative feedback. But even line driver op-amps are nowadays good enough to have negligible crossover distortion.